# How can I scan and get a PDF file with selectable japanese text?

Tags: pdf, scanning, ocr

I have several magazines in japanese. I would like to carry them to read in an airplane but they are too heavy so ideally I am thinking of scanning the pages and carrying them as pdfs. But I like to make annotations so selectable text is desired.

What is the simplest way to achieve this? (I heard adobe acrobat can be used but I would like free tools)

Edit: I read that modern scanners have OCR capabilities so today I tried scanning a page. I just got a huge image. No text selection possible. :(

Comment: Google "OCR scanning" - whether there are free tools that does it is unknown to me (I use Acrobat Pro).

Comment: Thanks. When I do that it usually means extracting text from an image to a text file. I am interested in just keeping it on a PDF file, not text file, and being able to select the text (for translation for example)

Comment: ... which simply means that you need something that is replicating Acrobat Pro.